# Macbook Pro Retina screen jerking

Tags: display

I have a brand new Macbook Pro Retina, MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E46). Every now and then the whole display jerks briefly down and then back up again in place. I haven't found any reference to this online. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience with Macbooks, I suspect there is either a loose connector, or (sigh) you have a dying chip on the motherboard (probably video controller).  Genius Bar should be able to diagnose for you pretty quickly.

Comment: It has started to shut down randomly now too. I'm hoping it's just a loose connector as it's barely 3 weeks old and was like that from the start. Going to the Genius Bar tomorrow.